# why run rails command from an rails application directory and non-rails directory differs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

a silly question:

when i run rails in an rails app , it shows

```
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
.....
```

but outside from rails app, it shows:

```
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
 -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
 .....
```

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb) you will see that it basically checks for existence of './script/rails' and runs it if it's found. So if there's no such - it just shows different output.